# Android PermissionsDispatcher - Ask for multi permissions, does not generate methods

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-library

I'm trying to user [PermissionsDispatcher](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher) for ask for multi permission,  works for request permissions, but don't  generates methods callback.

Someone already use for it?

**Project and Environment info:**

- Android Studio 2.3.1
- buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

gradle.

```
//Permissions
compile 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.3.2'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.3.2'
```

Multiple permissions request does not works. (**does not generates denied and never ask again flow.**)

```
@NeedsPermission( {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
      Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
      Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE})
void canGo() {
    //Permissions ok, go to next flow step.
}
```

if I change for unique permission works fine and generates denied and never ask again flow.

```
@NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
void canGo() {
     //Permissions ok, go to next flow step.
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours trying to solver it, I have figured out how to the lib works to ask for multi permissions. According to issue-57 on official repor.

> @OnPermissionDenied is called when request of @NeedsPermission which
>   has same string array as arguments is denied.

If we have the following method.

```
@NeedsPermission( {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
      Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
      Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE})
void canGo() {
    //Permissions ok, go to next flow step.
}
```

So, we also need to have:

```
@OnPermissionDenied( {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
      Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
      Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE})
void deniedPermissionsFlow() {
    //Permissionsdenied, block next flow step.
}
```